# Redirect Based On Access

Tags: java, php, redirect, dns, minecraft

I know this may not be possible. Here is my question. I have a domain. It is for my game server (Minecraft). I would like to be able to have my domain be typed in as example.com in both the game client and the browser url, and go to different places. In the browser, it would redirect to the website, and in the game client, it would redirect to the game server IP. I can give more clarification if needed. Thanks

Comment: This isn't a good fit for StackOverflow (programming related solutions). Instead, it should be moved to ServerFault or webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: What protocol does the game client use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible already because the Minecraft server's socket is listening to a different port than an HTTP port.

You should be able to run a webserver and a Minecraft server without any modifications because HTTP listens on port 80 and Minecraft runs on port 25565.

**NOTE**:

If you are at home, then you will need to also set your router to allow port-forwarding for those two ports. Also, port 80 may become blocked by your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [SRV record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record) so game server requests go to one place and web requests go to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the server that the domain name is forwarded to you can use. If you are using a linux server I would recommend IP Tables. [Example of Port Forwarding with IP Tables](http://fclose.com/b/linux/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/)